# Creating variable names using cells from an array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, import

I am attempting to write a script to import a large .txt file containing multiple columns of data into seperate variables within Matlab.

I have reached a stage where I have my 7 datasets:

```
Var1= 3230 x 1 double
Var2= 3230 x 1 double
Var3= 3230 x 1 double
Var4= 3230 x 1 double
Var5= 3230 x 1 double
Var6= 3230 x 1 double
Var7= 3230 x 1 double
```

and an array containing all of the variable names in different cells:

```
nameArray= 1 x 7 cell
```

My question is: how do I create variables with the same names as those within nameArray and subsequently populate them with data from my datasets?

Comment: What about [struct](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html?nocookie=true) with variables's names as fields?

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to write a universal script that will work every time I need to import data. The variable names may change on different imports so predefining them is not an option, they have to be taken from the .txt file every time.

Comment: @samstevens92 you can dynamically create struct field names - it will be cleaner than creating variable names dynamically. But leaving them as a cell matrix is probably the best option (i.e. instead of having `Var1`, `Var2` etc have `Var{1}`, `Var{2}`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Use `assignin`:

   ```
   assignin('caller', nameArray{1}, Var1)
   assignin('caller', nameArray{2}, Var2)
   ...
   ```

   This will create a variable with name `nameArray{1}` and value `Var1` in the namespace of the *caller*.
2. Build a struct:

   ```
   x = struct()
   x.(nameArray{1}) = Var1
   ...
   ```

   This builds a struct with dynamically assigned fields.
3. As [@Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009788/scott) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26991557/4177384): Use `readtable`:

   ```
   T = readTable('mydatafile.txt')
   ```

   This yields a similar result as option 2. But `T` is of type `table` and not `struct`. Tables are availble in Matlab versions R2013b and newer.

And of course you should use a loop

Comment: The `struct` option is a much better solution in my opinion.

Comment: @am304 I agree. But the first option answers the question most precisely.

Comment: I have indeed used the `struct` option with success. I did explore the `readtable` function previously however the format of the .txt file is rather strange and the columns did not did not remotely line up with the data, leading to incorrect variable names. Many thanks to everyone for their advice.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using `T = readTable('mydatafile.txt')`. This allows you to load a file with seperate columns and access those colums using their column name, for example like this: `T.MyFirstColumn`. See the manual on [readtable](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) for some examples.